# Is it possible to display multiple objects in 1 enhanced list?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to build an enhanced list that pulls records from 3 different objects and displays it into the same list and put that into a home page component. apex:enhancedList seems like the perfect way to go about this except for the fact that it appears you can display only one object type in the enhanced list. Is there any way to pull records from 3 objects into the enhanced list? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

From the API for enhanced list: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm

> type -    String  - The Salesforce object for which views are displayed, for example, type="Account" or type="My_Custom_Object__c".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `enhancedList` is really just a useful way of displaying the stock list views. If you want to show different objects, you're going to have to come up with some way of encapsulating them so that they have the same interface (an inner class on your controller is often a way to handle this), and then leverage the `apex:dataTable` component.